# Multiplying 1D matrixes like 2D matrixes

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am trying to multiply a 1D matrix as a 2D matrix in C. 
Here is one example of what result I get with a 2D loop: 
(the + should be a * I miss typed)

[image: 2D matrix multiplication]

So I get a matrix C with the values

```
{
{2,3},
{6,11}
};
```

Here is the code for the 2D array in C:

```
void multiply(int n, double ** a, double ** b, double ** c) {
int i, j, k;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++){
        for (k = 1; k < n; k++){
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];   
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to do the same, but for a 1D matrix, like in the picture:
(the + should be a * I miss typed)

[image: 1D matrix multiplication]

And here is the code for the 1D array:

```
void multiply(int n, double * a, double * b, double * c) {

int i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n*n; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < n*n; k++) {
            c[i]+= a[j]*b[k];
        }
      }
    }
}
```

After running it, I get the result `{14400, 14400,14400,14400}` instead of `{2,3,6,11}`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137934/discussion-on-question-by-r-nbkd-multiplying-1d-matrixes-like-2d-matrixes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to do matrix multiplication while working with one-D arrays instead of 2-d. Not sure why you'd want to do that but you could do something like this:

```
void multiply(int n, double *a, double *b, double *c) {

    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                c[i * n + j] += a[i * n + k] * b[k * n + j];   
            }   
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: So you are interpreting the question as storing a matrix in a 1D array rather than a 2D array?

Comment: Yes. That is what I gather from the details provided. They want the same answer whilst operating on 1-D arrays instead of 2-d.

Comment: @BijayGurung yes this is what I want, but with this loop that you wrote, I don't get the result `{2,3,6,11}` but `{56, 62, 68, 74}`

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: After looking more closely, this looks like the correct interpretation of the question. My original reading seems to be way off.

Comment: @BijayGurung I am calling it like this:  `multiply(mSize, a, b, c);`

Comment: Here is the complete code: [code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdHRPbnp4TDRhS0E)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ya. The given equations are misleading. Usage of (+) and placement of the names as well as the values of the matrices in the equation is confusing.

Comment: @BijayGurung It should be actually a dot (*) I miss typed, sorry

Comment: Two things: Now, `mSize = atoi(argv[1]);` which would mean `mSize * mSize` gives the overall length of the 1D array. 

And then in printMatrixByRows, use: `for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {`

Comment: @BijayGurung thank you very much, I did some other changes in the code and your loop works correctly

Comment: @R.Nbkd You do need to initialize your output matrix with zeros. Something like `for ( i = 0; i < n*n; ++i ) c[i] = 0;` before the triple nested loop will do.